# Error while upgrading to 5.1.2: Fail to upgrade database ExecutionException: NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

We're facing problems when upgrading to SonarQube v5.1.2 (from v4.3).

We made two attempts but unfortunately both failed.
Do you know how the problem can be solved?

The first lines of sonar.log:

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.2/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process2340632225276692772properties
INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438669636197] version[1.4.4], pid[1922], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438669636197] initializing ...
INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1438669636197] loaded [], sites []
INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438669636197] initialized
INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438669636197] starting ...
INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1438669636197] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/172.18.131.174:9001]}
INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1438669636197] sonarqube/9CC-OoQhRdmgJA5FerS6Ow
INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1438669636197] new_master [sonar-1438669636197][9CC-OoQhRdmgJA5FerS6Ow][sonar.xxxxx-yyyyy.com][inet[/172.18.131.174:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1438669636197}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438669636197] started
INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1438669636197] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -server -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.2/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.2/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/ojdbc6.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process1374933862508638147properties
INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /home/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.2/web
INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
```

And here are the trailing lines from sonar.log file:

```
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 258201 requests processed (1528 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 347558 requests processed (1489 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 480274 requests processed (2211 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 599469 requests processed (1986 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 723744 requests processed (2071 items/sec)
INFO   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1438625732248] [gc][young][6048][167] duration [889ms], collections [1]/[1.5s], total [889ms]/[3.7s], memory [139.7mb]->[64.8mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [80.4mb]->[582.5kb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [10.2mb]->[14.3mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [48.9mb]->[49.9mb]/[857.6mb]}
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 851566 requests processed (2130 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 990080 requests processed (2308 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1123117 requests processed (2217 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1252505 requests processed (2156 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1383991 requests processed (2191 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1508978 requests processed (2083 items/sec)
WARN   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1438625732248] [gc][young][6403][338] duration [1.1s], collections [1]/[2.5s], total [1.1s]/[6.8s], memory [169.3mb]->[79.2mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [86.8mb]->[1.7mb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [16.6mb]->[9.2mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [65.8mb]->[68.2mb]/[857.6mb]}
WARN   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1438625732248] [gc][young][6418][345] duration [2.7s], collections [1]/[3.4s], total [2.7s]/[9.6s], memory [137mb]->[42.9mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [99.7mb]->[1mb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [13.1mb]->[14.3mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [24.1mb]->[27.5mb]/[857.6mb]}
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1643805 requests processed (2247 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1757738 requests processed (1898 items/sec)
WARN   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1438625732248] [gc][young][6514][400] duration [2.9s], collections [1]/[3.1s], total [2.9s]/[13.3s], memory [143.1mb]->[60.5mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [81.3mb]->[2.1kb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [15.1mb]->[13.1mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [46.6mb]->[47.3mb]/[857.6mb]}
WARN  web[o.e.transport] [sonar-1438625732248] Transport response handler not found of id [6348]
INFO  web[o.e.client.transport] [sonar-1438625732248] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][sonar][inet[/127.0.0.2:9001]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.2:9001]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] request_id [6348] timed out after [5437ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:366) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
    org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:77)
    org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.execute(IndexSynchronizer.java:87)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:852)
    org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1824543 requests processed (1113 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1824543 requests processed (0 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1824543 requests processed (0 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1824543 requests processed (0 items/sec)
INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1824543 requests processed (0 items/sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sonar.log, it seems your search server(elastic search) which is running on port 9001 is timing out.

org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.2:9001]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] request_id [6348] timed out after [5437ms]
Pls check whether your network is slow. Take the thread dump of searchserver what it is trying to do while upgrade. You can find the process id of search server using  command :
netstat -lpn | grep 9001
once you have process id , you can use jstack pid to take the thread dump.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `sonar.log` extract you provided, you are facing a connection timeout from the ElasticSearch HttpClient to the ElasticSearch server embedded in SonarQube.

When migrating to 5.1.2, some ES indexes are (re)created. This what the various `2015.08.03 21:59:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] XXXXX requests (YYYY items/sec)` logs indicates.

Right before the error is raised, we see a lot of these logs but also GC warning from ElasticSearch (the `WARN   es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1438625732248] [gc][young][6514][400] ...` logs). If we look at the duration, we see it increases up to 2.9s. During this time, ElasticSearch's JVM is not doing anything but collecting memory, especially responding to connections from the client, hence the timeout.

The indexing is quite CPU intensive (since the GC logs indicates not much memory is used in ElasticSearch).

Your options are:

- increase the HttpClient's connection timeout, I couldn't find how to do that after a quick search
- increase CPU power (you might be on a VM)

Comment: Where can I increase the HttpClient's connection timeout?
In _sonar.properties_ or _wrapper.conf_?